# Should command line option processing logic and logging logic be a separate function or part of the main loop in a Python program

Tags: python

I am an intermediate level Python Programmer and I have written a Python program that scrapes Mutual Fun NAV data from a web site and inserts those into a database.

The code is around 176 lines long and has logic related to command line option processing using the argparse module and logging logic using the logger module.

Right now the entire logic around command line option processing and logging is part of the main() loop.  Should the logic for these be encapsulated in their own little functions or be part of main?

What do proper design principles require?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite template to separating logging, argument parsing and the *essential* work of a script or application.

```
def the_real_work( option, option, *files ):
    etc.

def build_parser( ):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ...
    return parser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig( ... )
    parser= build_parser()
    # parser.add_option( -v for verbose logging )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # tweak logging if there's a -v
    the_real_work( args.option, args.option, args.files )
    logging.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 2):

Proper design principles require the code to be readable and easy t maintain. If there are functions, they should be self-contained and (at least theoretically) re-usable, otherwise there's little sense in them.

Command line processing usually takes place at the very beginning of the program execution, I'd consider placing it in a separate function if the code for it grows too large (the function would return a dictionary with the parsed settings).

Logging code is frequently interleaved with the logic that does the actual stuff, but if you have heavy logging, offloading it to a separate function can help making the code easier to maintain (of course, extracting code to a function doesn't always make it better to read, especially not when a lot of data needs to be passed to the function and the likelihood of it being ever reused is low, which is a sign of bad function design).

Answer (score 2):

It's largely a matter of personal taste.

As a rule of thumb, you don't want any single function to be "too long", say, not so long that you can't see it all on one screen.

If you have dozens of command line options, you might move the arg parsing out of main(). If you have dozens of lines of code that sets up logging, you might move that out of main().